# Solving linear system of differential equations by Sympy in user defined function

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

```
t, C1, C2= symbols("t C1 C2")
x, y =  symbols("x y", cls = Function, Function = True)
eq1 = Eq(3 * diff(x(t), t), y(t))
eq2 = Eq(diff(y(t),t), - 3 * y(t) - 15 * x(t) + 4 * 1)
soln = dsolve((eq1, eq2), ics = {x: 5, y: 0})
soln
```

It works well.
However

```
t, C1, C2= symbols("t C1 C2")
x, y =  symbols("x y", cls = Function, Function = True)
ics = {x: 5, y: 0}
eq1 = Eq(3 * diff(x(t), t), y(t))
eq2 = Eq(diff(y(t),t), - 3 * y(t) - 15 * x(t) + 4 * 1)
def solve_ode_ivp(eq1, eq2, ics):
    soln = dsolve((eq1, eq2), ics)
    return soln
solve_ode_ivp(eq1, eq2, ics)
```

gives error message  TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'. It has problem with ics, but I don't know why and how to modify solve_ode_ivp to work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When typing `ics= {x:5 , y: 0}` in the first version you specify that the optional parameter ics will have this dictionary as value, in your second version you send it in as the second parameter (which is not ics)

You can change it to this:

```
t, C1, C2= symbols("t C1 C2")
x, y =  symbols("x y", cls = Function, Function = True)
ics = {x: 5, y: 0}
eq1 = Eq(3 * diff(x(t), t), y(t))
eq2 = Eq(diff(y(t),t), - 3 * y(t) - 15 * x(t) + 4 * 1)
def solve_ode_ivp(eq1, eq2, ics):
    soln = dsolve((eq1, eq2), ics=ics)
    return soln
solve_ode_ivp(eq1, eq2, ics)
```